# I get an error when I host my discord.py bot on replit

Tags: discord.py, replit

When I host locally it works but when I host on replit it gives me this error. Initially I thought it was due to the server part I created via [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnb1-beuRB4&ab_channel=M692) but the error comes directly from the main bot. What could be the problem?

Hosting a free bot has become quite a challenge lately. Why should I spend money on vps if my project is small?
error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 401, in <module>
    client.run(TOKENS)
  File "/home/runner/PeppeBOT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/PeppeBOT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/PeppeBOT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/PeppeBOT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/runner/PeppeBOT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/PeppeBOT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 680, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 795444d5a895b0c3 &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2023-02-06 13:35:25 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">795444d5a895b0c3</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">34.74.131.130</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

<script>(function(){var js = "window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'795444d5a895b0c3',m:'Dd87hwfU_SGSbuhSCmEIgD4OJgNU9bZXc65YvwTsSWk-1675690525-0-Af7JL6WCgpne12E1VutyYAlLnWrvoh/+MVaM+Dch+KEt5KTJYCZEFTRYzIAIqarUap1plo8VlvVhzUe1OB/Hw0FA7SealXU/Uq/+mAJjPxLFRi9lCCCmdMNpckywRQaZz7LVgUU9VefBQqqQ2Il04v0=',s:[0x33c1ad0932,0xfae449c46d],u:'/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b'};var _cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/scripts/cb/invisible.js?cb=795444d5a895b0c3',document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.nonce = '';_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

discord bot code

```py
import discord
from discord import client
from discord import app_commands
from webserver import keep_alive
import datetime
import asyncio
import os

print("PeppeBOT si sta avviando...")

class VerifySelectMenuTipologia(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Giocatore", description="Se vuoi partecipare ai nostri tornei!"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Spettatore", description="Se vuoi solo assistere ai nostri tornei!")
            ]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Seleziona la tua tipologia:",max_values=1,min_values=1,options=options)
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.values[0] == "Giocatore":
            self.spettatore = 918003194519511060
            spettatore = interaction.guild.get_role(self.spettatore)
            await interaction.user.add_roles(spettatore)
            self.svincolato = 917269610556968970
            svincolato = interaction.guild.get_role(self.svincolato)
            await interaction.user.add_roles(svincolato)
        elif self.values[0] == "Spettatore":
            self.spettatore = 918003193982644224
            spettatore = interaction.guild.get_role(self.spettatore)
            await interaction.user.add_roles(spettatore)
        self.membro = 918025325538078750
        membro = interaction.guild.get_role(self.membro)
        await interaction.user.add_roles(membro)
        self.attività = 917117040035237939
        attività = interaction.guild.get_role(self.attività)
        await interaction.user.add_roles(attività)
        self.boh = 1058541599455465483
        boh = interaction.guild.get_role(self.boh)
        await interaction.user.remove_roles(boh)
        await interaction.delete_original_response()

class VerifySelectMenuTipologiaView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout = 180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.add_item(VerifySelectMenuTipologia())

class VerifySelectMenuFasciaEta(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="18+", description="Se sei maggiorenne!"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="14-17", description="Se sei tra i 14 e i 17 anni!"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="13-",description="Se hai meno di 14 anni!")
            ]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Seleziona la tua fascia d'età",max_values=1,min_values=1,options=options)
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.values[0] == "18+":
            self.maggiorenne = 1071955516252758167
            maggiorenne = interaction.guild.get_role(self.maggiorenne)
            await interaction.user.add_roles(maggiorenne)
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Manca solo l'ultima selezione! Sei un giocatore o uno spettatore?", view=VerifySelectMenuTipologiaView())
        elif self.values[0] == "14-17":
            self.mezzo = 1071955345532014652
            mezzo = interaction.guild.get_role(self.mezzo)
            await interaction.user.add_roles(mezzo)
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Manca solo l'ultima selezione! Sei un giocatore o uno spettatore?", view=VerifySelectMenuTipologiaView())
        elif self.values[0] == "13-":
            self.minorenne = 1071955284534247534
            minorenne = interaction.guild.get_role(self.minorenne)
            await interaction.user.add_roles(minorenne)
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Manca solo l'ultima selezione! Sei un giocatore o uno spettatore?", view=VerifySelectMenuTipologiaView())

class VerifySelectMenuFasciaEtaView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout = 180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.add_item(VerifySelectMenuFasciaEta())

class VerifyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title='Verifica'):
    nickname = discord.ui.TextInput(
        label="Nickname di haxball:",
        placeholder="Scrivi qui il tuo nickname di haxball (ricorda non potrai più cambiarlo)",
        min_length=1,
        max_length=10,
    )
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.user.edit(nick= f'{self.nickname}')
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Ottimo! Ora seleziona la tua fascia d'età", view=VerifySelectMenuFasciaEtaView(), ephemeral=True)

class VerifyButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Verificati", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="verify_button")
    async def verify(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        if type(client.role) is not discord.Role: client.role = interaction.guild.get_role(918025325538078750)
        if client.role not in interaction.user.roles:
            modal = VerifyModal()
            await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Sei già verificato!", ephemeral=True, delete_after=10)
class PersistentViewBot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents = discord.Intents.all())
        self.synced = False
        self.added = False
        self.role = 918025325538078750

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id=917112143420215338))
            self.synced = True
        if not self.added:
            self.add_view(VerifyButton())
            self.added = True
        print(self.user, " si è avviato!")
        print("ID :", self.user.id)
        global logs_moderazione
        global logs_generali
        logs_moderazione = self.get_channel(917274076962258975)
        logs_generali = self.get_channel(917274597466972230)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=0x03c03c
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Avvio/Riavvio del Bot!',
        )
        await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1006702784797749288))
        await logs_moderazione.send(embed=embed)
        await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))

client = PersistentViewBot()

tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
guild_id = 917112143420215338

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    firstrole = guild.get_role(1058541599455465483)
    await member.add_roles(firstrole)
    tab1 = guild.get_role(918002005040046100)
    await member.add_roles(tab1)
    tab2 = guild.get_role(918003746850623529)
    await member.add_roles(tab2)
    tab3 = guild.get_role(918003750944272425)
    await member.add_roles(tab3)
    tab4 = guild.get_role(917119249145798716)
    await member.add_roles(tab4)
    mention = member.mention
    guild_id = member.guild
    member_count = guild_id.member_count
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=str(f"{mention} è entrato su **{guild}!**\nIn tutto ora ci sono **{member_count}** membri."),
        color=0x222222
    )
    await logs_generali.send(embed=embed)

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    name = member.mention
    guild = member.guild
    member_count = guild.member_count
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=str(str(f"**{name}** è uscito da **{guild}!**\nIn tutto ora ci sono **{member_count}** membri.")),
        color=0x222222
    )
    await logs_generali.send(embed=embed)

#Comandi di Moderazione
#Clear [COMPLETO]
clear_cooldown = app_commands.Cooldown(1,600)
def clear_cooldown_checker(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return clear_cooldown
@app_commands.checks.dynamic_cooldown(clear_cooldown_checker, key=lambda i: (i.user.id))
@tree.command(name = "clear", description = "Cancella gli ultimi messaggi inviati ", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def clear(ctx, limit: int):
    await ctx.response.defer(ephemeral=False, thinking=False)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xa61022
    )
    if limit == 0:
        embed.set_author(
            name="Non puoi cancellare 0 messaggi!",
        )
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        app_commands.Cooldown.reset(clear_cooldown)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0x03c03c
    )
    if limit == 1:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Ho cancellato ufficialmente un messaggio!',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
    else:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Ho cancellato ufficialmente {limit} messaggi!',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit, before=ctx.created_at)
    await ctx.followup.send(embed=embed)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xFFD000
    )
    if limit == 1:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{ctx.user.name} ha cancellato un messaggio',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
    else:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{ctx.user.name} ha cancellato {limit} messaggi',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Messaggi cancellati da:',
        value=f'{ctx.user.name}',
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Quantità:',
        value=f'{limit}',
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Canale dove è stato eseguito il comando:',
        value=f'{ctx.channel.mention}',
        inline=True
    )
    await logs_moderazione.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await ctx.delete_original_response()
@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    await ctx.response.defer(ephemeral=False, thinking=False)
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        cooldown = error.cooldown
        cd = round(cooldown.get_retry_after())
        time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=cd))
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"**Riprova tra `{time}`**",
            color=0xa61022
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name="Sei in cooldown!",
            icon_url=ctx.user.avatar
        )
        await ctx.followup.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await ctx.delete_original_response()

#acclear [COMPLETO]
@tree.command(name = "acclear", description = "Cancella con accuratezza gli ultimi messaggi inviati ", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def acclear(ctx, message_id: str):
    await ctx.response.defer(ephemeral=False, thinking=False)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xa61022
    )
    def message_limit(m):
        messageID = message.id
        return m.id != messageID
    channel = ctx.channel
    try:
        message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    except:
        embed.set_author(
            name="Non ho trovato il messaggio!",
            icon_url=ctx.user.avatar
        )
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        return 0
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0x03c03c
    )
    embed.set_author(
        name=f'Ho cancellato fino al messaggio:\n{message.content}',
        icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
    )
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000, before=ctx.created_at, check=message_limit, after=message)
    if message.content == "":
        await ctx.followup.send(embed=embed)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=0xFFD000
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{ctx.user.name} ha cancellato fino al messaggio:\nNon ha testo',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name='Messaggi cancellati da:',
            value=f'{ctx.user.name}',
            inline=True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name='Fino al messaggio:',
            value=f'Non ha testo',
            inline=True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name='Canale dove è stato eseguito il comando:',
            value=f'{ctx.channel.mention}',
            inline=True
        )
        await logs_moderazione.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await ctx.delete_original_response()
    else:
        await ctx.followup.send(embed=embed)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=0xFFD000
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{ctx.user.name} ha cancellato fino al messaggio:\n{message.content}',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name='Messaggi cancellati da:',
            value=f'{ctx.user.name}',
            inline=True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name='Fino al messaggio:',
            value=f'{message.content}',
            inline=True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name='Canale dove è stato eseguito il comando:',
            value=f'{ctx.channel.mention}',
            inline=True
        )
        await logs_moderazione.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await ctx.delete_original_response()

@tree.command(name = 'verifybutton', description='Crea il bottone per verificarsi', guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def verifybutton(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=str("Benvenuto nel server, prima di poter accedere a tutti i canali è importante verificarsi rispondendo a delle domande molto semplici ossia."),
        color=0x222222
    )
    embed.set_author(
        name='PeppeBOT',
        icon_url=f'{client.user.avatar}'
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Haxball Biglassic')
    embed.add_field(
        name='Domande:',
        value="1.Qual è il tuo nickname di haxball?\n2.Qual è la tua fascia d'età?\n3.Sei uno spettatore o un giocatore?",
        inline=False
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Come rispondere alle domande:',
        value="Nella prima domanda dovrai decidere quale nick di haxball utilizzare per questo server senza poterlo cambiare in futuro (ovviamente con le sue regole).\nNella seconda domanda dovrai specificare la tua fascia d'età tra:\n**1.** 13-\n**2.** 14-17\n**3.** 18+\nNella terza domanda dovrai semplicemente dirci se sei venuto per giocare ai tornei organizzati da noi (e quindi essere un effettivo giocatore) oppure se sei venuto semplicemente per conversare e guardare le partite del torneo da spettatore.",
        inline=False
    )
    await ctx.channel.send(embed = embed, view = VerifyButton())
    await ctx.response.send_message(content="** **", delete_after=0.1)

sesso_cooldown = app_commands.Cooldown(1,10)
def sesso_cooldown_checker(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return sesso_cooldown
@app_commands.checks.dynamic_cooldown(sesso_cooldown_checker, key=lambda i: (i.user.id))
@tree.command(name = "sesso", description = "Cancella gli ultimi messaggi inviati ", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def sesso(ctx):
    print(sesso_cooldown)
    await ctx.response.send_message("andrea")
    await ctx.edit_original_response(content="andrea2")
    app_commands.Cooldown.reset(sesso_cooldown)

@sesso.error
async def sesso_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        cooldown = error.cooldown
        cd = round(cooldown.get_retry_after())
        time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=cd))
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"**Riprova tra `{time}`**",
            color=0xa61022
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f"Sei in cooldown!",
            icon_url=ctx.user.avatar
        )
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        for i in range(10):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            cd = round(cooldown.get_retry_after())
            time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=cd))
            embed = discord.Embed(
                description=f"**Riprova tra `{time}`**",
                color=0xa61022
            )
            embed.set_author(
                name=f"Sei in cooldown!",
                icon_url=ctx.user.avatar
            )
            await ctx.edit_original_response(embed=embed)

keep_alive()
TOKENS = os.environ['SECRET_DISCORD_TOKENS']
client.run(TOKENS)
```

webserver

```py
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route("/")
def home():
  return "sono vivo"

def run():
  app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port= 8080)

def keep_alive():
  t = Thread(target=run)
  t.start()
```

Comment: The message is obvious isn't it? You sent too many requests and got rate limited

Comment: no for me it is not

Comment: Hi peppewarrior. I had the same issue, and I think it's got to do with the way you keep alive your bot making POST requests to your app. I changed servers and didn't get the error anymore. Replit is just not good for hosting discord bots.

Comment: Greetings. Alternative free hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when your bot has sent too many requests in a short amount of time. To resolve this, type `kill 1` in the shell (located in the bottom window of the Replit IDE) and hit enter. This will halt your bot's processes and reset its connection. Remember to rerun the bot to reconnect.